# Div within a div continues background-image

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image: I want white rectangle be a continuation of body background-image]

I have div(child) within a div(parent). Parent have red background-color with opacity.Is there a way to give the child body's background-image continuation?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://d6scj24zvfbbo.cloudfront.net/306f4bc782c04bbe4939f8c174349ca3/200000014-608bd61835/27122266-blood-wallpapers.jpg?ph=697a238450');
  color: white;
}

.lvl2 {
  margin: 30px 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #99000090;
}

.lvl3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#img-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
}

#image {
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>
  <div class='lvl2'>
    <h1 class='center' id='Sukuna'>Ryomen Sukuna</h1>
    <p class='center'></p>
    <div class='lvl3'>
      <div id="img-div">
        <img src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/03/04/dd03044d67c493a3514b1fe8f8c42cff.gif' id='image'>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='tribute-info'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Main Info</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Personality</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Abilities and Powers</li>
      </ul>
      <p>If you wanna know more about him see <a href="https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Sukuna#Jujutsu" target="_blank">this page</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `give the child body's background-image continuation`?

Comment: @ksav Forgive me if I explained wrong (I have bad English). I want the white part to be completely transparent.

Comment: @ksav but when I write transparent, it takes background color of parent. Is it real to give it background of body?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, it sounds like you want to make the `.lvl3` element background transparent, is that correct? See snippet below to see if this is what you desire

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://d6scj24zvfbbo.cloudfront.net/306f4bc782c04bbe4939f8c174349ca3/200000014-608bd61835/27122266-blood-wallpapers.jpg?ph=697a238450');
  color: white;
}

.lvl2 {
  margin: 30px 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #99000090;
}

.lvl3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#img-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
}

#image {
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>
  <div class='lvl2'>
    <h1 class='center' id='Sukuna'>Ryomen Sukuna</h1>
    <p class='center'></p>
    <div class='lvl3'>
      <div id="img-div">
        <img src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/dd/03/04/dd03044d67c493a3514b1fe8f8c42cff.gif' id='image'>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='tribute-info'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Main Info</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Personality</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>Abilities and Powers</li>
      </ul>
      <p>If you wanna know more about him see <a href="https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Sukuna#Jujutsu" target="_blank">this page</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```